# Inheritance not working as tutorial. what is the problem?

Tags: python

I'm studying 'inheritance' in Pycharm.
I just followed tutorial. And it doesn't work. What's the problem

```
##Chef.py##
class Chef:

    def make_chicken(self):
        print("The chef makes a chicken")

    def make_salad(self):
        print("The chef makes a salad")

    def make_special_dish(self):
        print("The chef makes bbq ribs")


##another.py##
from Chef import Chef

class another(Chef):

##app.py##
from another import another
a = another()

a.make_salad()
```

run>>>

error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NEWS1/PycharmProjects/exc/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from another import another
  File "C:\Users\NEWS1\PycharmProjects\exc\another.py", line 9

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

What is the problem....

Comment: You started a class block with no contents, resulting in a syntax error. You at least need to `pass` within the body of the class.

Comment: _What is the problem...._ ..... _SyntaxError_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your 'another' class, there's nothing following the colon. You can either add methods to the class or just a 'pass' like so

```
##another.py##
from Chef import Chef

class another(Chef):
    # other content
    pass
```